# Mapping exception when using discriminator in Grails 2.0.0

Tags: grails, grails-orm

At general I have problem with mapping: `org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: os.comida.StoreDocumentRw column: Type (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")`

To introduce the problem: I have many document types where each document type differs just a little bit from any other. All of them have common properties: date, number, issuer etc. So I decided store all document types in one physical table (one - it's very important for me). To implement this I wanted use hibernate discriminator.

Below I'm pasting my source code. I have there a base class `StoreDocument` and two document types `StoreDocumentRw` and `StoreDocumentWz`.

```
class StoreDocument {

    String type
    Date documentDate
    
    static mapping = {
        table '"StoreDocument"'
        version false
        id column:'"StoreDocumentID"', generator:'sequence', params:[sequence:'STORE_DOCUMENT_SEQ']
        discriminator column: '"Type"'
        documentDate column:'"DocumentDate"'
        type column:'"Type"'
    }    
    
}

class StoreDocumentRw extends StoreDocument {

    String rwSpecificData
    
    static mapping = {
        discriminator value: 'rw'
        rwSpecificData column:'"RwSpecificData"'        
    }
}

class StoreDocumentWz extends StoreDocument {

    String wzSpecificData
    
    static mapping = {
        discriminator value: 'wz'
        wzSpecificData column:'"WzSpecificData"'
    }
}
```

And when I'm trying run an app I get mentioned earlier `org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: os.comida.StoreDocumentRw column: Type (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")`

When I add `type insertable: false, updateable: false` to `StoreDocumentRw` mapping, it's still the same.

When I add `type insertable: false, updateable: false` to `StoreDocument` mapping, it's even worse:

```
ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Unsuccessful: create table COMIDA2."StoreDocument" ("StoreDocumentID" number(19,0) not null, "DocumentDate" timestamp not null, "Type" varchar2(255 char), "Type" varchar2(-1 char) not null, "WzSpecificData" varchar2(255 char), "RwSpecificData" varchar2(255 char), primary key ("StoreDocumentID"))
ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - ORA-00957: duplicate column name
```

So I don't know where I should put this insertable/updateable thing to make it working. I'm using Grails 2.0.0 and Oracle 10g. Can anybody tell me what's wrong with my code?

---

### Solution:

My mapping in `StoreDocument` was wrong. It's enough to cut `String type` and `type column:'"Type"'` and edit discriminator mapping like this `discriminator column:[name:'"Type"',length:50]`, which in result gives:

```
class StoreDocument {

    Date documentDate
    
    static mapping = {
        table '"StoreDocument"'
        version false
        id column:'"StoreDocumentID"', generator:'sequence', params:[sequence:'STORE_DOCUMENT_SEQ']
        discriminator column:[name:'"Type"',length:50]
        documentDate column:'"DocumentDate"'
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `StoreDocument` you have `String type` and `discriminator column: '"Type"'`, so from your exceptions it looks like Grails is trying to create two columns of name type.  Try changing the name of your `String` or discriminator-column and see if that corrects the issue.

To get around the issue with generating a varchar(-1) field try this: `discriminator column:[name:'Type',length:10]` from this JIRA [GRAILS-5168](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-5168). Of course, change the length to whatever you need.

Comment: Hm.. I'd like `String type` be used as a discriminator column. When I comment `String type` and `type column:'"Type"'`, then Grails tries to create `"Type" varchar2(-1 char) not null` which causes error `ORA-00910: specified length too long for its datatype`. Btw I'm using  `dbCreate = 'create-drop'` in my datasource. So does it indicate that I have to create a db structure on my own to avoid this `varchar2(-1 char)`?

Comment: Try this: `discriminator column:[name:'Type',length:10]` from this JIRA [GRAILS-5168](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-5168).  Of course, change the length to whatever you need.

Comment: Ok, this works. Thank you. If you edit your original answer and paste the above comment, I'll accept your answer.